# iPhone: Hierarchy of Views and SubViews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

A beginner's question:

I've created a subview in my view. In that subview I created yet another subview. Each subview fills the entire screen (320x480):

```
[self.view addSubview:aView]; // 320x480
[aView addSubview:yetAnotherView]; // 320x480
```

If I understand this correctly, this will lead to the following hierarchy:

- TOP: yetAnotherView
- MIDDLE: aView
- BOTTOM: view

So far so good. My problem is, that I would like to recognise gestures on the very top of these views (whatever view that may be... in my case it is yetAnotherView, I suppose). The following command WON'T work -- I guess because the view is hidden by the subviews:

```
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
gestureStartPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
```

Is there a way to tell the compiler that it shouldn't take self.view but **whatever view is on top of all the other views**?

Any help would be very much appreciated!

---

EDIT:

I think my problem is that the subviews I am editing are fullscreen UITextViews... and I guess I can override the touches on them? e.g. a swipe from right to left should work, but what about a swipe from bottom to top (that usually scrolls the uitextview -- unless I set it to scrolling unabled).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the touchesMoved:withEvent: method

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Then you can use this:

```
UITouch *touch1 = [[event touchesForView:self.someView] anyObject];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just realised that the problem is that I am trying to use fullscreen UITextViews as subviews... and I guess you can't use gestures on them, right?